# date range query in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am new to Cassandra.

We have table structure is like this

`CREATE TABLE keyspace.events (
    id bigint,
    msg_time bigint,
    status int,
    uuid timeuuid,
    message text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, msg_time, status, uuid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (msg_time ASC, status ASC, uuid ASC)
CREATE INDEX timestamp ON hh_keyspace.game_events (msg_time);`

We insert data with TTL of 32 days. Analytics team wants only last 1 day of data. Query with msg_time > '' ALLOW FILTERING will have huge performance impact.

Analytics team run the query daily. Are there any other ways to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the best way is to duplicate the data because writes are cheap in Cassandra. We write to another table with different key structure.

Ref:

1) http://blog.websudos.com/2014/08/16/a-series-on-cassandra-part-1-getting-rid-of-the-sql-mentality/ (Section - 4. Duplicate data and maintain consistency at application level)

2) http://blog.websudos.com/2014/08/23/a-series-on-cassandra-part-2-indexes-and-keys/ (Section - Secondary indexes)

Answer (score 0):

> Query with msg_time > '' ALLOW FILTERING will have huge performance impact.

ALLOW FILTERING means SURELY TIMEOUT on a normal production dataset. No surprise here.

> Are there any other ways to get the data

Model your table so that the query (give me the last day of data) is very fast.
How many **events** do you expect to have, for the biggest load ever possible, **per day** ?

Comment: events will be around 30M per day

Comment: I also thought of having another cluster with 1 day TTL. Take the backup on whole cluster and restore it on secondary cluster. But I found it is not possible to alter the TTL for the existing data.